# Parallel for with omp

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I try to optimise the following loop with OpenMP:

```
    #pragma omp parallel for private(diff)
    for (int j = 0; j < x.d; ++j) {
        diff = x(example,j) - x(chosen_pts[ndx - 1],j);
        #pragma omp atomic
        d2 += diff * diff;
    }
```

But it runs actually 4x slower than without `#pragma`.

**EDIT**

As Piotr S., coincoin and erenon pointed out, in my case `x.d` is so small, that's why parallelism makes my code run slower. I post the outer loop too, maybe there is some possibility for multithreading: (x.n is over 100 millions)

```
float sum_distribution = 0.0;
// look for the point that is furthest from any center
float max_dist = 0.0;

for (int i = 0; i < x.n; ++i) {
    int example = dist2[i].second;
    float d2 = 0.0, diff;
    //#pragma omp parallel for private(diff) reduction(+:d2)
    for (int j = 0; j < x.d; ++j) {
        diff = x(example,j) - x(chosen_pts[ndx - 1],j);

        d2 += diff * diff;
    }
    if (d2 < dist2[i].first) {
        dist2[i].first = d2;
    }

    if (dist2[i].first > max_dist) {
        max_dist = dist2[i].first;
    }

    sum_distribution += dist2[i].first;
}
```

If someone is interested, here is the whole function: https://github.com/ghamerly/baylorml/blob/master/fast_kmeans/general_functions.cpp#L169, but as I measured 85% of the elapsed time comes from this loop.

Comment: What is the value of x.d?

Comment: Looks like `d2` has become a bottleneck here: all threads will need to access the same memory. Faster would be to let each thread keep track of its own sum, adding these thread-specific sums together when the loop is done. I think you can do this by adding a `reduction(+,d2)` to the first pragma

Comment: @erenon x.d = 3 in my test

Comment: @brm i removed the atomic and changed the first pragma to '#pragma omp parallel for private(diff) reduction(+:d2)' but same result

Comment: @user1930254 creating threads consumes time as well, nor is thread syncrhonization free, is it worth doing this to execute 3 iterations?

Comment: @PiotrS. it was just a test, im running it with 8 iterations, but it produces an even worst slowdown.

Comment: As mentionned having critical sections take time so for small x.d it would hinder performance. Your computation workload (diff = ...) is not sufficient enough in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the outer loop, as posted, can be parallelized with OpenMP.
All variables modified in the loop are either local to an iteration or are used for aggregation over the loop. And I assume that calls to `x()` in the calculation of `diff` have no side effects.

To do aggregation in parallel correctly and efficiently, you need to use an OpenMP loop with `reduction` clause. For `sum_distribution` the reduction operation is `+`, and for `max_dist` it's `max`. So, adding the following pragma in front of the outer loop should do the job:

```
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum_distribution) reduction(max:max_dist)
```

Note that `max` as a reduction operation can only be used since OpenMP 3.1. It's not that new, so most OpenMP-enabled compilers already support it, but not all; or you might use an older version. So it makes sense to consult with the documentation for your compiler.

Comment: your suggested code causing a Segmentation fault error.

Comment: I do not see why it might not work, even after looking at your actual code. You may try a couple of things: check if it works with just one thread by adding `num_threads(1)` clause to the pragma; remove `reduction(max:max_dist) and instead add #pragma omp critical` before the second `if` statement.

Comment: I removed the max_dist part from the for loop. Actually it is not needed. Here is the code with some benchmark results: http://pastebin.com/NCnd0tdg. Results are looking good, the only problem; after 8 prints there is no more std::cout, and it seems only one core is busy (out of four). The program keeps running without any further output. Without pragma runs as expected, but significantly slower.

Comment: Since you have posted another question on the new problem, is there anything else with this initial question that still needs to be clarified?

Comment: No, i think the for loop's problem is solved. It is parallel now, and there is a speed up.